# Get throughput for custom duration in Dropwizard metrics

Tags: metrics, codahale-metrics

I am using Dropwizard metrics with the rolling-metrics library to get performance metrics. For throughput, I am able to get 1, 5 and 15 minute rates by using `getOneMinuteRate(), getFiveMinuteRate() and getFifteenMinuteRate()` methods. 
I want to get the throughput for a custom duration, say 10 second rate. Is this possible and if so can someone please tell me how I can do this?